# oracle query to view list of data type

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, datagridview

I try to show my table data type in datagridview vb.net. Here is the sample code :

```
        oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" _
      + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & txtServer1.Text & ")(PORT=" & port1.Value & ")))" _
      + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=" & txtSID.Text & ")));" _
      + "User Id=" & txtUsername1.Text & ";" _
      + "Password=" & txtPassword1.Text
        Dim connOracle As New OracleConnection(oradb)

        Try
            connOracle.Open()
            connOracle.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
        Finally
        End Try

        SQL = "desc hr.employees"
        myCommand1.Connection = connOracle
        myCommand1.CommandText = SQL
        myAdapter1.SelectCommand = myCommand1
        myAdapter1.Fill(myTablePreview)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myTablePreview
```

I try login using username "system". When I run this code, I got error message "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

is there any wrong with my query??
pls helpme. thank's.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DESC (DESCRIBE) is a SQL*Plus command, not a SQL verb. SQL*Plus is a front-end tool for SQL, so it adds some commands of its own, and this is one of those. You have to stick with SQL when using OLE DB.

If you want this data in a client program, you might want to try something like:

```
select * 
from all_tab_columns 
where table_name = '<your table name>'
```

or like this:

```
Select COLUMN_NAME 
from user_tab_columns 
where table_name='EMP'
```

This is pure (Oracle) SQL, which you can experiment with in SQL*Plus until you get the set of columns that you need.

Devian Yudha,

Comment: yeah  that's totally what I mean but I got little problem when put in that query on my code. VB.Net cannot identify <'> sign. That query become comment now.

So, how to resolve this problem??
Thank's for any help..

Comment: <your table name>, is that what you mean?
you can change it with your table.
select * 
from all_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'DEPT'

Comment: yupz, it was just example hehe. dont use it.
and if you wanna use a Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) you can read from this post in the first place. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

`DESC` is a SQL PLus command.

you probably want to do an actual query, like

```
select * 
from all_tab_cols
where table_name = 'EMP'
```